# Add_action inside of another add_action

Tags: wordpress, hook

I'd like to have this hook be used

```
foreach($admin_page_hooks as $hook){
    add_action('admin_head-'.$hook, 'add_headernew');
}
```

but I want to have it be called after the wp side menu has been uploaded any ideas?

Comment: Still need help if anyone can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching

```
add_action('admin_head-'.$hook, 'add_headernew');
```

With

```
add_action('in_admin_header'.$hook, 'add_headernew');
```

It was being called before the wpwrap div and now its called inside of the wrapper.